# Can I generate a continuous PNG spritesheet using Flash?

Tags: flash, sprite, tween, blit

If I have acomplex timeline animation with a series of shape and motion tweens, is it possible to export all the separate frames as a sequence of sprites in one huge PNG sheet?

There is a great jQuery plugin, called [jBlitter](http://glowfilter.com/blog/jblitter-animated-html5-canvas-buttons/) which accepts such PNG spritesheets, and turns them into animated buttons or other UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to advance to each frame of the mc and add its pixels to a BitmapData by using its draw() method.  At that point, you should be able to send its bytes to a server to be saved, but you'll have to search to figure out how to do that.

HTH;

Amy